# Normal Android/windows app with blockchain storage

Tags: android, windows, blockchain, decentralized-applications

So I am building an android/windows app for a library management system that is close to release, as of now the app stores the data either locally (on device) or in the cloud (Gdrive, Onedrive).
I have been studying about blockchain and I was wondering if an existing android app like mine can integrate with blockchain to store data? If so, How do you do that?
Mind you, I do not want to build a new dapp, I just want to store the data generated by the users of my app in a blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ipfs to store data of your dapp.
Basically ipfs is also like a blockchain.
When you send data to ipfs it gives you a hash than you can publish that hash on blockchain.
Ipfs is free.
And when you store data directly to blockchain, it will be costly than storing a simple hash.
That hash will be used to identify ur data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ipfs is used with dapps right? I wanted to know if I can store the data of a normal android app (NOT a dapp) on blockchain.

Comment: Yes you can!!!  Also you can store you website on ipfs